# My bst insertion keeps on overriding recently added value in C

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

it seems to me that I may be overlooking something in my code but please help me see it. 
Whenever I call this function to insert a new node, it keeps on overriding the
most recent node.

```
node_t *node_insert(node_t *cur, char name[]){
    int diff = -1;
    if(cur == NULL) {                 
        node_t *new_node = (node_t*)malloc(sizeof(node_t)); 
        strcpy(new_node->name, name);          // copy data
        new_node->right = new_node->left = NULL;                    
        return new_node;                          `
    } else {
       diff = strcmp(name, cur->name); 
       if(diff<0){
          return node_insert(cur->left,name );}
       else if(diff>0){
         return node_insert (cur->right,name );}
       else if (diff ==0) {               
           return NULL;
        }
    }
}
```

The function above is then called down below as such:

```
int bst_insert(bst_t *tree, char name[]){
    node_t *result = node_insert(tree->root, name); // update node
    if(result == NULL) {            // duplicate found, ignore
        return 0;                   // 0 indicates not modified
    } else {       
        tree->root = result;       
        tree->size++;               // size now larger
        return 1;                   // 1 indicates modifed
    }
}
```

Comment: When `cur` is NULL, you create and return a new node. But the recursive calls don't do anything with that return value, except return it to the next level. It's not clear how you expect the new node to get attached to the proper location in the tree. A [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) might clear that up.

Comment: Hey @user3386109 I just updated my code so you can see when the function is then called. In the main function I'd just call bst_insert function

Comment: `tree->root = result;` is correct only when `tree->root` is `NULL`, that means when the tree is empty. After that you've constantly updating the root node with the new node, thus forgetting the old tree.

Comment: You need a total redesign. I would start by writing a `create_node` function. In `bst_insert` you can attach the node to the root when the root is NULL. Otherwise, call the `node_insert` function. But `node_insert` should have a return type of `void`. It should find the proper place to attach the new node, then create the new node and attach it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comments, `tree->root = result;` is correct only when `tree->root` is `NULL`, that means when the tree is empty. After that you've constantly updating the root node with the new node, thus forgetting the old tree.

Your `node_insert` function creates a new `node_t` object, that's OK. Then you do
the recursion, you find the spot where you would have to insert the new node,
but you just return the new node without adding. The information **where** to
add the new node is lost.

You only have to modify your `node_insert` a little bit:

```
int node_insert(node_t **cur, char name[]) {
    int diff = -1;
    if(*cur == NULL) {                 
        node_t *new_node = calloc(1, sizeof *new_node);
        if(new_node == NULL)
            return 0;

        strcpy(new_node->name, name);
        *cur = new_node;
        return 1;
    } else {
       diff = strcmp(name, (*cur)->name); 
       if(diff<0){
          return node_insert2(&((*cur)->left),name);}
       else if(diff>0){
         return node_insert2(&((*cur)->right),name);}
       else if (diff ==0) {               
           return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you have to pass a double pointer to a `node_t` object. If `*cur` is `NULL`,
then you create a new `node_t` object and assign it to `*cur`, thus changing the
location (to the newly created object) where the original pointer was pointing to.

In the recursion it is only a matter of passing a pointer to the `left` pointer and `right` pointer. If the
recursion finds the right node and `left` (or `right` depending on the value of
`diff`), then you pass a pointer to the pointer to the next recursion, where `*cur`
will be `NULL` and the new node will be appended to.

Bear in mind that the way you create a new `bst_t` tree is important,
`tree->root` **must** be initialized with `NULL`, otherwise the `node_insert`
function will fail with undefined behaviour when it is doing the recursion.

Note how I create a new node. I use `calloc` because it initialized the new
memory to 0, thus `new_node->left` and `new_node->right` will point to `NULL`.
There is one thing I don't like about your creation of a new node though:

```
strcpy(new_node->name, name);
```

Since we haven't seen how you declared the structs, it's difficult to know if
that's correct. If `node_t->name` is a `char*`, then you would need to allocate
memory for that and then do `strcpy`:

```
new_node->name = calloc(strlen(name) + 1, 1);
if(new_node->name == NULL)
{
    free(new_node);
    return 0;
}

strcpy(new_node->name, name);
```

or if your system has `strdup`

```
new_node->name = strdup(name);
if(new_node->name == NULL)
{
    free(new_node);
    return 0;
}
```

But if `node_t->name` is a `char[SOME_LENGTH]`, the `strcpy` is not the right
choice, because you have no guarantee that the string in `name` is shorter than
`SOME_LENGTH - 1`. In this case you would have to use `strncpy` and make sure
that you end up with a valid string:

```
strncpy(new_node->name, name, sizeof new_node->name);
new_node->name[sizeof(new_node->name) - 1] = 0;
```

And of course you don't have to forget to free the memory you've allocated.

Now you can update your `bst_insert` to:

```
int bst_insert(bst_t *tree, char name[]){

    int ret = node_insert(tree->root, name);

    if(ret)
        tree->size++;

    return ret;
}
```